# Error: Objective C: GLES2 File not Found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In the code bellow it says that there is an error and that 'GLES2/gl2ext.h' File not Found.  Does anyone know were to add the file or what the file is.  Thanks

Code with error:

```
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Xcode 6, I had to make the following change to one my projects:

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Pendleton.  Thats fixed that error but now I have 3 others all the same saying:  Too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1. This is the code.  It is in three different places.  glGenVertexArraysOES(_vertexArray);   glGenVertexArraysOES(0);     glGenVertexArraysOES(_vertexArray);

Comment: Each of those calls should have two arguments instead of one. The first argument should be an integer, and the second argument should be the pointer to an array. Where did you get the code from? I'd check it to make sure you didn't accidentally modify it.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this and Just starting out on my first app.  Just having problems getting it sorted out.  How would you add a source

Comment: Sorry, I'm not asking you to do something to the project. I'm just asking for the URL of the article/tutorial you are following so that I can see if there's anything there I can use to help you.

Comment: I'm not following anything.  I have this app on the App store as I made it about 6 months ago. I have not really looked at the project for a while since I got it published on the app store. But now I have decided to update it. Since Xcode 6 has come out it has come up with heaps of errors and I'm not sure where they have come from. It never use to have them but just when I tried to build it for the first time when I open the project it came up with heaps of errors.

Comment: That's really weird. From what I can tell, the `glGenVertexArraysOES` function has always required 2 arguments. Perhaps it is better to ask this question to someone who knows OpenGL. What happens if you replace each of those calls with: `glGenVertexArrayOES(1, &_vertexArray);`?

Comment: Ok thanks. I might try that and see if it works. Anyway thanks for all your help.